# pandas read_html does not storing complete data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am using read_html function in pandas to extract data from some html tables . But for some reason the output gets cut after a certain size :

example  :

```
0     RECKITT BENCKISER INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED  Vs.ST...
1     SMT. SONY AND ANOTHER  Vs.  STATE OF UTTARAKHA...
2     BHATIA BHAWAN DHARAMSHALA  Vs.  STATE OF UTTAR...
3     MOHD. YASEEN AND OTHERS  Vs.  STATE OF UTTARAK...
4     DR. ADITYA PRAKASH SINGH  Vs.  STATE OF UTTARA...
5     DR. MANOJ KUMAR UNIYAL  Vs.  STATE OF UTTARAKH...
6     DR. LALIT MOHAN PANDEY  Vs.  STATE OF UTTARAKH...
7     SUBHAM SAINI AND ANOTHER  Vs.  STATE OF UTTARA...
```

In each case here the table should have stored STATE OF UTTARAKHAND (+ more data)

from source code :

```
<span class="style2">RECKITT BENCKISER INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED
</span><br><span class="style4"> Vs.</span><br><span  
class="style2">STATE OF UTTARAKHAND AND ANOTHER
</span></td><td width="20%"
```

How to resolve this issue.

I am simply doing :

```
df = pd.read_html(test,flavor='html5lib',header=0)
print (df)
```

Comment: Include the url you are getting the table from.

Comment: url was part of some response : http://pastebin.com/raw/p7vfb2JG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is getting the complete text. It was not showing the full text due to limited column width.

Check this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('max_colwidth',400)
df=pd.read_html('http://pastebin.com/raw/p7vfb2JG')[0]
df.head()
```

Output:

[image]